# Import SQL database with apostrophes into MySQL through PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My sql file is about 10MBs and its extremely hard to find and replace all the `'` (apostrophes) one by one. When I import the sql file as a zip file into my mysql database through phpmyadmin, it finds all the apostrophes and asks me to fix them. How can I import this successfully? Is there a quick way to find and replace all the `'`s? Thanks

**What the file looks like**

This is a Wordpress site so it `insert`s wp_comments like below

`in trade so here's an opportunity`

`it's up to them`

`website's information section`

etc etc

Comment: How does the "broken" sql look like? Just provide a small self-explanatory part

Comment: @zerkms I updated the question with sample lines that make issues

Comment: It's not sql, they are just strings. So what is the broken sql?

Comment: Can you give me an example of a broken sql? Im new to sql. What basically happends is when I try to import my sql wordpress database I get this error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 've accomplished in the past twelve months. The WordPress community is stronger t' at line 1"

Answer (score 0):

You just want to replace something in bulk?

You mean like:
Ctrl+H (replace all)?

Comment: In programming it's better to solve the roots of the issue, not the consequences.

Comment: His question was,
    Is there a quick way to find and replace all the 's?
I'd normally agree, but since he didn't really provide enough information to effectively do what you suggested, I simply directly answered what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Apostrophes (quotes) are perfectly normal in a .sql file; what is not normal is a statement like this:

insert into sometable(col1) values('Hi it's me');

The inner quote character should have been escaped like this

insert into sometable(col1) values('Hi it\'s me');

or

insert into sometable(col1) values('Hi it''s me');